# On the quadratic equivalence of fields

Tags: knot-theory, fields, quadratic-forms, brauer-groups

I have spent the past two years studying abstract Witt rings. These objects are a generalization of "The Witt ring of a field," an algebraic invariant of fields of characteristic not equal to 2. Classic examples are $W(\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{Z}$ and $W(\Bbb{C})=\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}.$ The study of these Witt rings of fields has produced  a family of abstract Witt rings of so-called "basic indecomposables." **The elementary type conjecture** suggests that every finitely generated Witt ring, abstract or arising from a field, can be constructed using Witt rings of elementary type, and consequently all abstract Witt rings would be realizable as the Witt ring of a field.

My question begins here.

If the elementary type conjecture is false, there would exist a basic-indecomposable Witt ring which either does not arise as the Witt ring of a field, or in the event that it does arise from a field would indicate that we have yet to classify all fields up to quadratic equivalence${}^*$.

> Other than those studying field theory, and algebraic number theory, what areas of mathematics/physics would care that the classification of fields up to quadratic equivalence is not complete?

One area that comes to mind is knot theory. Quadratic forms, in particular the symmetrised Seifert quadratic form associated to the 
Seifert surface, are connected via the Witt ring as an obstruction 
to what is called sliceness of a knot.

Any information would be extremely helpful.

${}^*$*Two fields are considered to be quadratically equivalent if their Witt rings are isomorphic. But that is rather tongue in cheek, as the Witt ring needs to be defined, too. That being said, two fields are quadratically equivalent if the collection of isometry classes of anisotropic symmetric quadratic forms over one field is in a one to one correspondence with the collection of isometry classes of anisotropic symmetric quadratic forms over another field, and this correspondence is compatible with Witt cancelation, the operation of orthogonal sum, and tensor product.*

Comment: What is quadratic equivalence of fields?  (Also, you seem to use 'field' with at least two (possibly three) different meanings in your blockquoted question, which is awkward.)

Comment: Happy to field complaints. I changed field to area in the block quote. Hopefully this will minimize awkwardness. Although, I must say it will be pretty difficult for me to avoid using some *word* that isn't already in use in mathematics. I also elaborated on quadratic equivalence. Let me know if anything else needs clarification or explanation.

Comment: I would mention that, in the past decade or two, the elementary type conjecture on abstract Witt rings was transformed to a conjecture about the maximal pro-2 Galois groups of fields. This gives a much wider perspective, since one can then extend it to maximal pro-p Galois groups for an arbitrary prime number p (see works by Efrat, Minac, ...).  There are indeed known connections between pro-p Galois groups (usually with restricted ramification) of fields and knot theory - see the various works by Labute, Alexander Schmidt, Morishita, to mention only a few names.

Comment: @user05811 Thank you for the feedback. I appreciate the list of authors, and I will look into their work. If you happen to remember anything specific, that would be extremely helpful. It is very difficulty to find any discussion of abstract Witt rings, as most folks have assumed the conjecture is true. Do you happen to know of the work being done for arbitrary primes, $p$?

Comment: Googling "elementary type" and "pro-p Galois groups" will give you several such papers.  For example I. Efrat, "Pro-p Galois groups of algebraic extensions of Q", J. Number Theory 64 (1997) 84-99, proves the conjecture in its pro-p form for fields as in the title.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating @user05811. I feel rather foolish for not googling it.